# Py2App error-- Function Not implemented

Tags: python, py2app

Sigh...Py2app is the devil. (Now that I've gotten that off my chest, I'll be professional)

I swear that I have done everything that PY2app asks me to do. I created the set up file, I have installed py2app correctly, but when I run the setup.py script via the command : python setup.py py2app:  it goes for a while and then crashes with:

*** creating application bundle: Adjudicator_Bones_1.4 ***
copying Adjudicator_Bones_1.4.py -> /Volumes/compression/QC/QCing/otherFiles/Area51/PythonAdjudicator/BareBones1.4/dist/Adjudicator_Bones_1.4.app/Contents/Resources
creating /Volumes/compression/QC/QCing/otherFiles/Area51/PythonAdjudicator/BareBones1.4/dist/Adjudicator_Bones_1.4.app/Contents/Resources/lib
creating /Volumes/compression/QC/QCing/otherFiles/Area51/PythonAdjudicator/BareBones1.4/dist/Adjudicator_Bones_1.4.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7

error: Function not implemented

Once this is done, I still have SOME kind of app to run and when I run it, the terminal comes up with a lovely error saying that a python runtime could not be located.

I should note that the script that I want to turn into an app will need to be distributed to other users and consists of multiple imported python files.

I am at my wit's end. I just do not know what to do. I am using Python 2.7, the latest py2app download.

Is there an easier way? can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I had this error when trying to run the setup.py from a SSHFS partition.